# Android SQLite not returning list of all rows

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on a little Android app, for the game EVE.

While working on the activity for adding new characters I created myself a class for database handling of all the CRUD operations and whatnot, which you can take a look at [here](http://hastebin.com/zayoromuhe.avrasm), but most importantly what my issue is that the `getAllCharacters()` method returns and empty List.

```
public List<Character> getAllCharacters() {
    List<Character> characterList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CHARACTERS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Character character = new Character();
            character.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            character.set_apiKey(cursor.getString(1));
            character.set_keyId(cursor.getString(2));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return characterList;
}
```

Is the code itself in the method, and the way I am using it is

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
List<Character> list = db.getAllCharacters();
```

and when trying to call `toString()` on it  I get `[]` as a value.

I can see the entries to the database being made, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFwkY.png).

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Where do you add to your `characterList`?  Why would it not be empty?

Comment: Thank you for proving me once again, that writing code on no sleep is a no-go. You sometimes need a fresh pair of eyes for such dumb problems..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add to your `characterList` once you create your `character` variable in your `do` section. Add a `characterList.add(character);` inside your `do` at the end and you should be good.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Please add following code

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Character character = new Character();
        character.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        character.set_apiKey(cursor.getString(1));
        character.set_keyId(cursor.getString(2));

        // add following
        characterList.add(character );

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

You are creating object of character but missed to add it into ArrayList ie. in characterList that's why it's returns empty List.